# jQuery (.click) function for multiple div classes

Tags: jquery, html, click

I'm trying to execute a single function for 3 different div classes within a web page. These 3 div classes contains hyperlinks in each and when these hyperlinks are clicked then the corresponding link should open in another div (here it is accessed with id(div id)).

my code goes here

```
       $('.div1 a, .div2 a, .div3 a').click(function() {
             var url = $(this).attr('href');
             var height = $('#divid').height();
             var width = $('#divid').width();
                $('#divid').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
              return false;
             });
```

div1, div2, div3 are div classes
divid is the id of the div section.

Upto my knowledge the code is correct but unfortunately it doesn't reflects within my site. Is there any wrong with this part.

Comment: try putting your code in between `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: Make sure you're including the jQuery library in your site's pages. Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `id="divid"` to the `<object>` you're replacing it with.

Comment: jquery library is included, no errors in browser. I couldn't spot where its going wrong

Comment: Blazemonger i think soo there wouldn't be any difference adding id="divid"..

Comment: one improvement :: when i replaced $('.div1 a, .div2 a, .div3 a').click(function() with $('a').click(function()... it works - the query executes for every hyperlink within the webpage. -- But, this is not what I want. I want to execute the query for the hyperlinks within the div classes (div1,div2,div3)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a single class for all three div and use this :

```
$('.singleclass a').on('click',function() {
             var url = $(this).attr('href');
             var height = $('#divid').height();
             var width = $('#divid').width();
                $('#divid').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
              return false;
             });
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Just a different way to do the same thing

Comment: While this is useful it really doesn't answer the OP's question about the code not working in his site.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue.

I added all the three div classes(div1, div2, div3) into one div (gave the class name and the id, then accessed the div with it's id. Eventually, the function applied for all the three classes.

I couldn't know what went wrong previously, but anyhow I solved it. Thank you all for your support.